# Anime where MC has Auto-Conquer Cheat

Tags: story-identification, anime

There is this modern fantasy (Low-Fantasy) story where some people have superpowers.
The mc has the superpower to 'conquer any land that he treads on'.
It's a harem power fantasy, or at least I'm pretty sure.

Comment: This question is very terse and probably matches a bunch of different animes. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://recommendmeanime.com/anime-about-conquering-the-world/